# What is the Jacobian?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, complex-numbers

What is the Jacobian of the function $f(u+iv)={u+iv-a\over u+iv-b}$?

I think the Jacobian should be something of the form  $\left(\begin{matrix}
  {\partial f_1\over\partial u} & {\partial f_1\over\partial v}  \\
  {\partial f_2\over\partial u} & {\partial f_2\over\partial v}
 \end{matrix}\right)$

but I don't know what $f_1,f_2$ are in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Recall that $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}$$ which should let you write $f$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Thank you, but $a,b$ are complex numbers and I am not sure how to split them...

Comment: If $f(z)=g(z)+c$ where $c$ is complex, then $f_1(z)=g_1(z)+\Re(c)$ and $f_2(z)=g_2(z)+\Im(c)i$.

Comment: You could just write $(u+iv-(a_1+a_2i))/(u+iv-(b_1+b_2i))$ where $u,v,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are real.  And later, exploit the [Cauchy--Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) to conclude that the matrix must have the form $\begin{bmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c \end{bmatrix}$ where $c$ and $d$ are some real numbers and $f'(z)=c+id$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write $(u+iv−(a_1+a_2 i))/(u+iv−(b_1+b_2 i))$ where $u,v,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are real.  Then multiply the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator to find the real and imaginary parts.

Then later, exploit the Cauchy--Riemann equations to conclude that the matrix must have the form $\begin{bmatrix} {}\ \ \  c & d \\ -d& c\end{bmatrix}$ where $c$ and $d$ are some real numbers and $f\;'(z)=c+id$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael.